# Taking variable from a API function JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been searching for an answer to get a variable from a function in JS but couldn't find any helpful solution. 
I have the following code :

```
 <script src="http://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP"></script>
     function getIP(json)
        {
            console.log( json.ip);
        };
```

now the issue is, I will need the IP address that its retrieve within this function only in another function. 
so I have a function call.

```
function x(){
console.log(json.ip); 
}
```

how can I access it in this function?  I even tried to return the var but didn't help.

Comment: One way it you have store json.ip in some global variable, and access it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store your ip in variable and access it whenever it is required

```
 <script>
      var myIp;
      function getIP(json)
            {
                myIp = json.ip;
            }
      </script>
      <script src="http://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP"></script>



     <script>
          function x(){
            console.log(myIp);  // 196.15.23.9
         }
         x();
      </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the general case, I'd have `getIP` resolve a global Promise. Then, whenever you need access to the value, call `.then` on the Promise:

```
const ipPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
  window.getIP = (json) => resolve(json.ip);
});
function x() {
  ipPromise.then((ip) => {
    console.log(ip);
  });
}
```

Note that your `json` variable [is *not* JSON](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) - it's a plain object. Something which is in JSON format must be a string, which is not what's going on here. Consider calling it something more suitable, maybe `ipifyResult`, or destructure the `ip` property immediately.